# What does Facebook need to accept an app review for just a script?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, instagram-graph-api, facebook-app-requests

we have a Facebook page of our company. We are also verified as company at Facebook.

Now we want to extract all the comments below posts on our page. For that I wrote a simple Python script to connect to the Graph API of Facebook. Everything works fine but to extract the name of the user who wrote a comment I need a permission like *pages_read_user_content*. To achieve that permission I have to walk through the whole complex app review process.

Facebook declined my request with the words that they can not check the app (script) and that they need access to it to test it. Wow, yes that is true but hey, I just wrote a script and do not want to build a whole web application just for that easy task.

Is it really necessary to build something with a test access or is it kinda avoidable? Did anyone go though that process or have some experience?

Thanks

Comment: The have instructions on how to submit "server-to-server" apps here, that probably comes closest in terms of purpose: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/create-an-app/server-to-server-apps

Comment: @CBroe Thank you. The page you mention had guided me but the request got declined. What about the testing part?